# Deleting columns and rows from a matrix by name [R]

Tags: r, matrix

I have a kinship matrix, which is essentially a list of IDs down and the same IDs across, like so:

```
ID1  ID2  ID3  ID4  ID5  ID6
ID2
ID3
ID4
ID5
ID6
```

And so on.  I would like to eliminate certain IDs from the matrix (that is, deleting the columns and the rows that of the IDs I don't want).  My matrix is 129 x 129 and my ID list that I want to keep is 60 IDs long.  I have tried the following code (with dummy data):

```
kinstmp <- matrix(c(0,0,1,0,1,0,
     0,0,1,0,0,0,
     0,1,1,1,0,0,
     1,0,1,0,0,0,
     0,0,1,0,1,0,
     0,0,1,0,0,0,
     0,1,1,1,0,0), nrow=6) #example of what my matrix looks like
kinstmp2 <- kinstmp[rownames(kinstmp) %in% id, ]
kins <- kinstmp2[,colnames(kinstmp2) %in% id ]
```

However, this results in no rows and columns being deleted.  Is there a way to get this to work?

An example of the id file is:

```
ID3
ID5
ID6
```

Comment: And change `kinstmp2[colnames(kinstmp2) %in% id,]` by `kinstmp2[,colnames(kinstmp2) %in% id]`

Comment: corrected - but still doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `dimnames` to your matrix, and make sure place the column condition on the right (literally) side of the comma.

```
nm <- paste0("ID", 1:6)
kinstmp <- matrix(c(0,0,1,0,1,0,
                    0,0,1,0,0,0,
                    0,1,1,1,0,0,
                    1,0,1,0,0,0,
                    0,0,1,0,1,0,
                    0,0,1,0,0,0), nrow = 6, dimnames = list(nm, nm))
kinstmp

id <- c("ID3", "ID5", "ID6")

# subsetting rows
kinstmp2 <- kinstmp[!rownames(kinstmp) %in% id, ]
kinstmp2
#     ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5 ID6
# ID1   0   0   0   1   0   0
# ID2   0   0   1   0   0   0
# ID4   0   0   1   0   0   0

# subsetting columns
kins <- kinstmp2[ , !colnames(kinstmp2) %in% id]
kins
#     ID1 ID2 ID4
# ID1   0   0   1
# ID2   0   0   0
# ID4   0   0   0

# or subsetting rows and columns in one call
kinstmp[!rownames(kinstmp) %in% id, !colnames(kinstmp2) %in% id]
```

Comment: Actually - that seemed to get rid of all IDs (not just the ones I didn't want).  Was curious also how to keep the IDs I do want.  Simply changing the code to (for e.g.) `kinstmp[rownames(kinstmp) %in% id, ]` didn't seem to work...

Comment: And so you should... My id list was wrong to begin with. :)